# Modal con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tabla el cual se le agregan `<td>` de ser necesario por el usuario para llenar datos en una especie de factura, la `<td>` se despliega y tiene el botón mas no apunta a la modal que muestra para llenar dicha información

```js
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#add").click(function () {
                // Obtenemos el numero de columnas (td) que tiene la primera fila (tr)
                var tds = $("#tabla tr:last td").length;
                var trs = $("#tabla tr").length;
                var nuevaFila = "<tr>";

                for (var i = 0; i < tds; i++) {
                    nuevaFila += "<td> </td>";
                }

                nuevaFila += "</tr>";


                 let miHermosoNuevoBoton = '<button >Click Me!</button>';

                let miHermosaNuevaFila = $.parseHTML(nuevaFila);
                $(miHermosaNuevaFila).find("td:last-child").append(miHermosoNuevoBoton);
                $("#tabla").append(miHermosaNuevaFila);

            });


            $("#del").click(function () {

                var trs = $("#tabla tr").length;
                if (trs > 1) {

                    $("#tabla tr:last").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="registro">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
```

Comment: Hola. No sé el resto, pero a mi al menos no me queda nada claro qué es lo que quieres y cuáles son los problemas que tienes. No muestras tu html, y por el poco html que muestras, parece que vas a tener un modal `#registro`, al que no haces ninguna referencia en tu javascript. Te invito a modificar tu pregunta dando muchas más información y aclaraciones, así como los problemas a los que te enfrentas ;)

Comment: solo requiero que con el js que se creo para añadir una nueva td, la cual incluye un boton(creado en la nueva td) el boton apunte a la modal con el id registro

Comment: Pero a qué te refieres con "que el botón apunte", quieres que abra una modal? (la cual no estamos viendo porque NO pones el código...). Tendrás que ser más concreto y mostrar qué has intentado hasta ahora, además de mostrar todo tu código, si no, yo al menos no te puedo ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No esta claro lo que quieres por lo que asumiré que usas `bootstrap` para crear el modal e intentas abrir el **modal** con el botón que creaste.

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
let miHermosoNuevoBoton = '<button onclick="$(\'#registro\').modal(\'show\');">Click Me!</button>';
```

Espero esto te sirva, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: genial eso era lo que buscaba, muchas gracias